# Selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, web-application

How to capture the 'capthca code' during registration a page using webdriver.

i tried to get the input and through to element (using find element on field). but, field is not recognized.

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of having captcha, if a script could capture it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want pass "classical capture" like this http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore, then my answer "There is no way".

For testing: you should test build without capture verification (Devs can create special build)

For hacking by webdriver  (f.e. You want to create google accounts by webdriver automatically) you should to explore "capture hacking"